# Mysql-Events: How get rid of Errors like No Data-zero rows fetched?

Tags: mysql, events, cursor

I just try to kill mysql jobs using event scheduler.
Unfortunately the event scheduler fills up my log file with error messages:
**No Data - zero rows fetched**

But I am catching the No data exception.

Why event still throws an error?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `kill_run_aways`( IN runtime INT(7), IN username VARCHAR(32) )
BEGIN
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE connid INT UNSIGNED;
        DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ID FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST 
            WHERE  COMMAND ='Query'
            AND TIME >= runtime AND USER = username;

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

        OPEN cur1;

        REPEAT
                FETCH cur1 INTO connid;
                IF NOT done THEN
                    select * from information_schema.PROCESSLIST where connid=ID;
                    KILL connid;
                END IF;
        UNTIL done END REPEAT;
        CLOSE cur1;
  END;
```

Thanks Arman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql says that `NOT FOUND` "is relevant only within the context of cursors and is used to control what happens when a cursor reaches the end of a data set" (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare-handler.html. So I believe you get this message when line `select * from information_schema.PROCESSLIST where connid=ID;` is executed.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I just commented out the select *  statement. the situation does not change. The procedure call throws always warning: 1329, which is later in events becoming as an error.

Comment: You can also try to add an empty handler for `SQLWARNING` : `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING BEGIN END;` to suppress warnings in your procedure

Comment: It is probably BUG in mysql 5.5 linux brunch,The event writes always errors in error logfile. I dont see this behaviour on 5.1 and on windows.

Comment: I read something about similar problem in mysql 5.5.8 (sorry, I don't remember where)... They say it's fixed in 5.5.10 and higher.

Comment: I just testing 5.5.12 the messages are still there, same for 5.5.10.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to your query in `CURSOR`. Next, after open command check whether your `CURSOR` returns more than one row, e.g.

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS '1' FROM DUAL;
OPEN cur1;
IF Select FOUND_ROWS() /* it concerns SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS */  > 0 THEN
    -- do sth
ELSE
    -- do sth else
END IF;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, but a bug/strange behaviour of MySQL causes the warning to appear even if it was handled. You can avoid that if you add a "dummy" statement to the end of your procedure that involves a table and is successful. This will clear the warning. (See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-warnings.html)

In your case:

```
SELECT ID INTO connid FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST LIMIT 1;
```

after the end of the loop. On MySQL 5.5.13 the warning disappears for Linux and Windows. I commented on MySQL Bug 60840 and I hope they will fix it some time in the future...